# Excess fat around jawline and hips

Tags: weight-loss, bellyfat

I'm quite fit, been going to the gym since August (stopped just into January and is about to start again) doing 60 forward leg swings and knee tucks (from hovering position), 30 reps on the ab wheel, 45 pull ups (front and back facing arms), 3 reps of plank for 1 minute, 45 seated chest pulls (50-60kg) and 45 shoulder presses.

I did the above 3-4 times a week, and started to go running (3-5 mile runs) on top of that because I didn't really notice a different to the amount of fat around my jawline, or any shrinking to the spare tire currently sitting around my hips.

I'm quite a slim guy, and lost a lot of fat at the gym and gaining mass. I'm roughly 5ft 11" and weigh roughly 80kg (same as when I stopped going to the gym in December).

How can I lose the excess fat around my jawline (particularly under the chin) and around my hips?

Is this ab exercise I do enough to get rid of the spare tire, or should I be doing different things?

Comment: Long story short; you don't choose where to lose fat. You lose it all over, or not at all.

Comment: @Alec So annoying, I'm slim all over! Just got a bit of chub on my jawline and a bit of a belly. Oh well, maybe after another few months..!

Comment: You could potentially consider lipo, but that's not something to be recommended online.

Comment: Like I said, I'm very slim. It's just odd when you've got something of a reverse Adonis' belt! Either way, I don't care enough to justify an operation, but thanks.

Comment: You're probably skinny fat and could use some strength training. Although this is just a guess.